# Apache Ignite Error - Failed to resolve class name [platformId=1, platform=.NET, typeId=318194342]

Tags: c#, ignite

Failed to resolve class name [platformId=1, platform=.NET, typeId=318194342]

Comment: What is your QueryEntity configuration? How do you insert the data?

Comment: How do you insert data? Can you provide a small reproducer project? There is a mismatch between the type of the data in the cache and the type used for the LINQ query, but it is hard to tell where it comes from without the code.

Comment: data is inserted using sql

Comment: To see the problem, I need a full code sample that creates the cache, inserts the data, and performs the query. There is a discrepancy with table and class names somewhere.